Size and usual height of an algebraic number
Let $a$ be an algebraic number of degree $n$. One defines its usual height $H(a)$ by $H(a)=\max_{0\le k\le n}|\alpha_k|$ where $P(X)=\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_kX^k$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb Z$, that is the $\alpha_k$ are relative prime integers and $\alpha_n>0$. Define the house of $a$ by the maximum of the moduli of the conjugates of $a$ and the denominateur of $a$ to be the positive generator of the ideal $\{u\in\mathbb Z\mid ua\text{ is an algebraic integer}\}$ of $\mathbb Z$. Then the size of $a$ is $s(a)=\max\{\mathrm{house}(a),\mathrm{denominator}(a)\}$. By Waldschmidt (Lemma 3.1 page 81, Diophantine approximation on linear groups), one has
$$H(a)\ge\sqrt{n+1}s(a).$$
But the given proof uses Mahler measure and Weil height. Can one prove this result directly by elementary means?
Thanks in advance for any answer.

Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

I am not sure how much more "elementary" you want than Mahler measure and Weil height

In an ideal world, only definitions and some undegraduate maths..
